# Refactor: Having a nested resource where the parent fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following resources setup:

```
resources :sites do
  resources :documents
  # more nested here
end


resources :documents do
  resources :notes, :except => [:show, :new, :edit]
end
```

I want the notes controller to have the document context. The problem is, the document controller itself depends on the site context. So the /document urls that are created from the above all throw a 500 error. I could adjust the controller code to handle this, but i wonder if there's a way to not create the /document urls, just: /document/#id/notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For any one else that may have this problem** You can restrict the routes you don't want by using :except just the way @agmcleod has for the :notes. So to restrict the document urls would either be:

```
resources :sites do
    resources :documents, :except => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    # more nested here
end
```

or

```
resources :documents, :except => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
    resource :notes, :except => [:show, :new, :edit]
end
```

You can remove any of the actions as necessary.

Comment: Have to admit, I couldn't remember my question here too well since it's back from november. I since did some restructuring on my models, and now that i have documents > versions > notes, i actually did just that. Used the except option to only load a couple routes i need for the parent resource. I accepted your answer, since it is correct.